# Linux SIFT Workstation Sleuthkit

Tags: linux

I am a university student and new to the Linux Environment. I've installed the Sleuth-kit via the cli using the .gz file. For some reason the the commands don't seem to be working and I've uninstalled the previous version as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By "installed [...] using the .gz file", you mean extracting it? Where did you extract it to? Is that destination part of your `PATH` variable? Edit your question to include the actual steps you took.

Comment: i followed the steps mentioned in the Readme.txt with ./Configure, install, sudo make install.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "don't seem to be working" - does the system not find them? it finds them but they don't run? they run but do not produce the expected output?

Comment: well normally i use mmls and <TAB> it would autocomplete but now it does not mml -V does not return the version it says it can't find it. just entering mmls now gives 

"The program 'mmls' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install sleuthkit
"

Comment: Does `find /usr -name mmls -print` produce any output?

Comment: nothing just returns to the prompt again.

Comment: Try `find / -name mmls -print`

Answer (score 0):

After doing the installation command in one line it seemed to have worked,

> configure;sudo make;sudo make install